# How Do I make a textview always on screen when other textview expands vertically?

Tags: android-layout

I have an android layout file with two textViews, the first one may contain long texts, expanding vertically along the screen space, and the other textview contains only one line of text.

Both textViews begin centered vertically on screen, with the second one being just bellow the first one.

It happens that the contents of the first textview can change, adding more text to it, and at some point the first textview expands and occupies the whole screen, pushing the second textview outside the screen.

I need that the second textview doesn't get pushed outside screen when it reaches screen bounds, the second textview must own the last piece of space on screen for its contents.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/firstTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/secondTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true" />

     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ConstraintLayout` to the rescue!

Dependency in your `build.gradle` inside `app` module:

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
```

Very basic layout for what you want to achieve should be like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="*YOUR ENDLESS TEXT HERE*"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/barrier"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="top"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="*YOUR SINGLE LINE TEXT HERE*"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Reason:

1. ConstraintLayout makes it much easier to develop, what you want to achieve.'
2. ConstraintLayout provides `Barrier`, which can stop expanding views beyond its boundary, which are referenced to it.

Here, in our case, here's what the layout does:
First `TextView` is expanded to stretch & cover the whole view that is available, second `TextView` is locked at the bottom, just as you want. Now the `Barrier` will prevent first `TextView` from scaling beyond its boundary, giving fixed space to the second one at the bottom.

**IMPORTANT:** To scroll your content inside first `TextView`, you need to add this line in your java file:

```
TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
text1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

The above declaration will help you scroll the content until it ends no matter how big it is, inside your `TextView` itself, so no `ScrollView` needed!

Hope this helps :)

**Reference:** [ConstraintLayout - Android Developer Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)